# how to display a table which has 3 appointments for each day of week in Struts 1

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

In Struts 1 , i am trying to display 3 appointments for each day of the week.

- each appointment of respective day has a 'from' and 'to' textbox , where the user has to enter the time.
- Every day has a `checkbox` , which when clicked enables the appointments of that particular day(ie enables 3 appointments ,ie 6 `textboxes`)

**Problem :** 
i don't know how to write DTO for this in java and write the loop on the JSP page to display this structure. i think i need a different name for every textbox so that i can access them individually and enable or disable them
please help me out.

I am using lists to display this structure.
the table is as follows:

```
<table border="0" width="50%">
<tr><div  class="alt_tab_color" align="center">Hours:</div></tr>
<tr class="alt_tab_color">
<td>Day</td>
<td>APP1(HH:MM)</td>
<td>APP2(HH:MM)</td>
<td>(HH:MM)</td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td>
<td> from To</td>
<td> from To</td>
<td> from To</td></tr>
<logic:notEmpty name="abcForm" property="daysListForm.daysList">
<logic:iterate id="subForm" name="orderSummaryForm" property="daysListForm.daysList">
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="normal_txt"><bean:write property="dayName" name="subForm"></bean:write></td>
<td><html:checkbox name="abcForm" property="daysListForm.dayEuFlag" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td><logic:iterate id="subForm1" name="abcForm" property="appointmentListForm.appointmentList" ><td>
<table>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><html:text property="from" name="subForm1" disabled="true"></html:text></td>
<td><html:text property="to" name="subForm1" disabled="true"></html:text></tr>
</table>
</td></logic:iterate></tr></logic:iterate></logic:notEmpty></table>
```

the forms are as follows :

```
public class DaysListForm extends ActionForm 
    private List daysList;
    private boolean dayEuFlag; 
    //getter setters

public class DaysForm extends ActionForm
private String dayName;
private AppointmentListForm appointmentListForm;
//getter setters

public class AppointmentListForm extends ActionForm
private List appointmentList;
    //getter setters

public class FromToInfoForm extends ActionForm
private String from;
private String to;
//getter setters
```

and i am populating them here :

```
public List populateDays(AppointmentListForm ftInfoListForm) {

    List<DaysForm> noteLists= new ArrayList();
    DaysForm mon = new DaysForm();DaysForm tue = new DaysForm();DaysForm wed = new DaysForm();
    DaysForm thu = new DaysForm();DaysForm fri = new DaysForm();DaysForm sat = new DaysForm();
    DaysForm sun = new DaysForm();
    mon.setDayName("Mon");tue.setDayName("Tue");wed.setDayName("Wed");
    thu.setDayName("Thu");fri.setDayName("Fri");sat.setDayName("Sat");
    sun.setDayName("Sun");

    noteLists.add(mon);noteLists.add(tue);noteLists.add(wed);
    noteLists.add(thu);noteLists.add(fri);noteLists.add(sat);
    noteLists.add(sun);

    mon.setAppointmentListForm(ftInfoListForm);tue.setAppointmentListForm(ftInfoListForm);wed.setAppointmentListForm(ftInfoListForm);
    thu.setAppointmentListForm(ftInfoListForm);fri.setAppointmentListForm(ftInfoListForm);sat.setAppointmentListForm(ftInfoListForm);
    sun.setAppointmentListForm(ftInfoListForm);
    return noteLists;
    }


public List populateFromTo(){


     List<FromToInfoForm> noteLists= new ArrayList();
     FromToInfoForm app1 = new FromToInfoForm(); FromToInfoForm app2 = new FromToInfoForm(); FromToInfoForm app3 = new FromToInfoForm();
    noteLists.add(app1);noteLists.add(app2);noteLists.add(app3);
    return noteLists;

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. `"I want.."` is not a great way to start a post. Can you please show us what you have tried, the relevant code and the **specific** issues you are having. Read up on [how to write a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) and have a look at the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on here. Then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25642035/edit) your question and give all the necessary details. Alternatively if you want someone to do it for you, there are freelancing sites where you can pay someone a fair price.

Comment: I am trying to implement it using lists , but the problem is every appointment textbox is getting the same name , hence whenever i click a checkbox all the 'from' textboxes get enabled/disabled

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the relevant code, and the **specific** error you are getting. I can't see your code, program, screen, errors, inputs, outputs or anything else.

Comment: i have added the code . please help me . i have no idea how to proceed ahead or what changes to make to the code